# Problem with tables (huge data) on Word-press site

Tags: jquery, table

I created bootstrap table for my word-press site.I created custom template to publish my table on my website.The problem is that my tables has a 2000 pages and each pages show 10 entries and consists of 7 columns.It took so much time to load this table.How can i avoid from this problem.Please help me on this and i am open to any other ways.Thank you for your kind support.

> index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo Server Side Process Datatable</title>
    <!-- bootstrap Lib -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- datatable lib -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Server Side Process Datatable</h1>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Categories</th>
            <th>Tags</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Download Link</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Categories</th>
            <th>Tags</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Download Link</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <!--create modal dialog for display detail info for edit on button cell click-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div id="content-data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var dataTable=$('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "ajax":{
                url:"fetch.php",
                type:"post"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> i share my code above.At the the end it will have a 20000 rows.Therefore i want to create a true pagination for this table.
>
> fetch.php

```
 <?php
    $con = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'blabla');

    if (!$con) {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }
    echo 'Connected to MySQL';


    $request=$_REQUEST;
    $col =array(
        0   =>  'ID',
        1   =>  'Title',
        2   =>  'Year',
        3   =>  'Categories',
        4   =>  'Tags',
        5   =>  'Type',
        6   =>  'Download Link',
    );  //create column like table in database

    $sql ="SELECT * FROM Table_46";

    $totalData=mysqli_num_rows($query);

    $totalFilter=$totalData;

    //Search
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM Table_46 WHERE 1=1";
    if(!empty($request['search']['value'])){
        $sql.=" AND (id Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR Title Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR Year Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' ";
        $sql.=" OR Categories Like '".$request['search']['value']."%' )";
    }
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $totalData=mysqli_num_rows($query);

    //Order
    $sql.=" ORDER BY ".$col[$request['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$request['order'][0]['dir']."  LIMIT ".
        $request['start']."  ,".$request['length']."  ";

    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $data=array();

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $subdata=array();
        $subdata[]=$row[0]; //id
        $subdata[]=$row[1]; //name
        $subdata[]=$row[2]; //salary
        $subdata[]=$row[4]; //age
        $subdata[]=$row[5];
        $subdata[]=$row[6];
                  //create event on click in button edit in cell datatable for display modal dialog           $row[0] is id in table on database
        $subdata[]='<button type="button" id="getEdit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="'.$row[0].'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">&nbsp;</i>Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">&nbsp;</i>Delete</button>';
        $data[]=$subdata;
    }

    $json_data=array(
        "draw"              =>  intval($request['draw']),
        "recordsTotal"      =>  intval($totalData),
        "recordsFiltered"   =>  intval($totalFilter),
        "data"              =>  $data
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the query you use to populate your table?  In your arguments ($args) if you don't include a parameter specifying the number of posts to return (posts_per_page) then it will display the default of 10 or whatever you have set in Settings>Reading.  You can read more about query parameters on this page, the settings for how many per page are way down the page under Pagination Settings: 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I share the code that  i used for this table.Please help me to create a true pagination for this.

Comment: sorry if my earlier comment wasn't clear - I need to see your SQL query for fetching the data from your database in order to populate your table, what you posted above is the HTML that is the structure for holding the data and some links to other scripts.  If you read the page I linked to, the Codex page on WP Query, you'll see some query examples and all of the arguments you can use to customize your query.  In the list of arguments is one for limiting the number of results per page (a 'pagination' parameter). Post your query so we can troubleshoot it.

Comment: First of all thank you for your kind support.Now i m using to get a table for my wordpress website by server side processing since it is consost of huge data.In above you can see my html and php files.But it is not get data from my local host.What  i missing i dont know.How can i correctly use this two file for my website.Thank you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be connected to WordPress, might be better asked at [so].

Comment: To @Trisha's point, you may want to use a WordPress query. There you can use pagination parameters to solve this issue. Another point I would make here, is that if you are using this in WordPress, you should at least be using the `wpdb` class methods for security.